# MongoDB C# Driver collcetion.Find(filter, "wanted to choose not to return _id").ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("filename", filename);
var list = await col.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

here are my code, I can't figure out what's the proper syntax to perform the task I wanted to do.

Comment: What is the task you want to do? Why do you not want to return _id?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. I guess you want the returned document contains no `_id` field. To do so, you need a `projection`.

Try

```
var projection = new BsonDocument("_id", false);
var list = col.Find(filter).SetFields(new FieldsBuilder<YourClass>()
    .Exclude(p => p.Id));
```

[reference](http://www.layerworks.com/blog/2014/11/11/mongodb-shell-csharp-driver-comparison-cheat-cheet)